# How to configure security.yml

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, routes

I've a problem with my `security.yml` using Symfony 2.

This is the content of my file :

```
security:
 encoders:
    MOD\UserBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: sha512
        iterations: 1
        encode_as_base64: false

role_hierarchy:
    #[...]

providers:
    user_db:
        entity:
            class: MOD\UserBundle\Entity\User
            property: username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern: ^/user/login$
        anonymous: true

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: false
        provider: user_db
        form_login:
            login_path: user_login
            check_path: user_check
        logout:
            path: user_logout
            target: /user/login
```

I have an entity called User, with fields : `id, email, username, password, salt, roles`

When I try to log me on from `/user/login` the result is always the same : `"Bad credentials"`.

Is there a way to check what happened on `user_check` request? Or any apparent mis-configuration in the `security.yml` ?

This is what I get in `app/logs/dev.log` :

```
[2014-02-09 21:35:27] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username AS username2, t0.password AS password3, t0.salt AS salt4, t0.email AS email5, t0.roles AS roles6 FROM User t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1 ["Maxime"] []
[2014-02-09 21:35:27] security.INFO: Authentication request failed: Bad credentials [] []
```

In my databse I have just one user with the username : `Maxime`

Comment: check the if you are setting some salt when hashing your password.
also check the length of your `password` field ( it may be small for the hashed password )

Comment: I set the `salt` to ''. My password is _admin_ so the hash is `C7AD44CBAD762A5DA0A452F9E854FDC1E0E7A52A38015F23F3EAB1D80B931DD472634DFAC71CD34EBC35D16AB7FB8A90C81F975113D6C7538DC69DD8DE9077EC`

Comment: and the length of your password in database ?

Comment: The max length is fixed to 255

Comment: emm could you post your entity and the logic where you store your useres in database before retrieving them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely solved my problem.
I change `security.yml` like that :

```
encoders:
        MOD\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 1
            encode_as_base64: true
```

And I save the password hashed with sha512 and base64 encoded.

It works !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zizoujab.
Since you asked me many questions about the password and the way to store this one in my DB I've finaly replace `sha512` by `plaintext` in my `security.yml`.
Then I try to logged me in with :
`maxime / C7AD44CBAD762A5DA0A452F9E854FDC1E0E7A52A38015F23F3EAB1D80B931DD472634DFAC71CD34‌​EBC35D16AB7FB8A90C81F975113D6C7538DC69DD8DE9077EC`
And it works.

Comment: its not secure to store passwords in plain text !

Comment: Of course ! I know and I don't want to do it. It was just to try. And now, I know that it's a problem with hash, so I'll search how to fix it.